# Break axis in R

Tags: r, graph, lattice

Recently I had some problems representing some data with `xyplot`. Everything appears very nicely but my boss asked me to break the axis (I'm not very fan of break axis). So far I have been able to do this with the function `shingle`, yet the order of panels is such a mess that read the information is imposible. In addition, I would like strips showing only the variable `cs` no the `st` (information specified in my sample data.frame) on the graphic. Then, the real challenge is to fix all this requirements into lattice, which is the internal standard for graphics in the group.

Here is my example data.frame (http://1drv.ms/1JOKSPU) sample of code:

```
AA<-read.csv("~/example.csv",header = T,sep = ";",dec = ",")
    AA$st <-
      shingle(Indl.Data$t,
              intervals = rbind(c(0, 14),
                                c(23, 26)))
    AA<-AA[with(AA, order(t)), ]



    my.panel.1 <- function(x, y, subscripts, col, pch,cex,sd,...) {
      low95 <- y-sd[subscripts]
      up95 <- y+sd[subscripts]
      panel.xyplot(x, y, col=col, pch=pch,cex=cex, ...)
      panel.arrows(x, low95, x, up95, angle=90, code=3,lwd=3, 
                   length=0.05, alpha=0.5,col=col)
    }
    xyplot( logOD~t|cs+st,
            data=AA,
            strip = T,
           sd=0,
            groups=cs,
            xlab = list("Time ", cex=1.5), 
            ylab = list("growth", cex=1.5),
            type="p",
            col=c("red","black"),
            scales = list(x = "free"), between = list(x = 0.5),
            panel.groups="my.panel.1", 
            panel="panel.superpose",
            par.settings = list(layout.widths = list(panel = c(6, 2))))
```

This is what I get with this:
[image: AS can be noticed upper line has the times higher than 24h and the lower line the lower times. My target is to make a continuum with an hypothetic panel 1( cs=X t0-t15) and next to it a narrower panel 2 ( cs=X t23-t26)]

In advance, sorry if there is any mistake in the formulation of my question, I do not have a programming background and this is me third question.

Cheers;

Comment: Search with the term "strip.custom" in SO (since there are many worked examples) and read its help page to address your question about the contents of the strips. I'm not able to help  on the rest because I don't understand what changes or additions are needed for the axes or layout. (The lattice package author was vehemently opposed to axis breaks.)

Comment: Well, I have already break the axis (that's why I have wide and narrow panels). However, they are not in order. For example the first two (upper left) are Ace(time 24-26)-fru (time 24-26) when it should be Ace(time 0-15)-Ace (time 24-26). 
Thanks for the tip about the strips, I will look at that carefully.

Comment: Attempting replicate this I get the error saying `Indl.Data` not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to go through `st` and then `cs`. So try `xyplot( logOD~t|st+cs,`.

Maybe use `layout=c(4,3)` if needed.  And `as.table=TRUE` if you want it to start in upper left.

Comment: You completely hit on the right nail! Going to the extra mile, I would like to what would be the way to change the display on the layout.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by changing the display on the layout. The layout is set by `layout = c(numColumns,numRows)` You just want an even number of columns since they come in pairs, Adjust to suit the layout you want. I first got an unsuitable layout for my graphic device, so I specified `c(4,3)`. The plot you showed is `c(6,2)`.